# How to run Jenkins Docker image/container success?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-container, docker-for-windows

I am using Windows 11 pro x64, Docker 4.12.0 (85629) . I follow guide at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/#on-windows

```
docker run --name jenkins-docker --rm --detach ^
  --privileged ^
  --env DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR=/certs ^
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client ^
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home ^
  --publish 2376:2376 ^
  docker:dind
```

[image]

Docker container log https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/ec283a3835016abe5329e3e0531099a1

[image]

[image]

How to run Jenkins Docker image/container success?

**Update:** If delete previous container, then I run

```
docker run --name vyjenkins -p 2376:2376 jenkins/jenkins
```

I go to https://localhost:2376/ , it also still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The document was wrong. Run command like this

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v D:\vyjenkins:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Go to http://localhost:8080/ , use auto-generated password like this `dce5c97f3ac14d99a8fd2d32127ced9c` .